# svg filter calculation resolution

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am applying an svg filter to a series of images and it appears the filter is only using the 4 highest significant bits of the color in its calculations, the rest are ignored and have no impact on the result. Is there a way to force the filter to include all 8 color bits in its calculations.

To illustrate my issue I have created a codepen that builds a set of 256 red cells increasing from 0 to 256 intensity in red only.
I then svg filter the cells with a linear scale that multiplies the bit value of the color of each cell by 128.

I should see the first two three cells (bit value 0,1,2) as 0, 128 and 256 intensity red and the rest should be 256 red.

What I see is that everything with a decimal value of less than 8 is 0 intensity.

This demonstrates that the first three bits are being ignored in the svg calculation. Why is this the case.

https://codepen.io/jgbgy/pen/LmVGxG

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Threshold</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
             width="1200" height="1024"
             viewBox="0 0 1200 1024" >

      <defs>

          <g id="colormap"></g>

          <!-- Filter Definition -->


         <filter id="linearred">
          <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="128" intercept="0"/>
          </feComponentTransfer>
         </filter>


      </defs>
        <g>
            <use id="source" xlink:href="#colormap"/>
            <use y="200"  id= "redoption2" xlink:href="#colormap" filter="url(#linearred)" />
        </g>

    </svg>
</div>
<script>

        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var svg = document.getElementById("colormap");
        var cellSize = 10;
        var colCount = 16

                for (let r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
                    var cell = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
                    var x = (r % colCount)
                    var y = Math.trunc(r/colCount)
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "width", cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "height", cellSize);

                    RcolorHex = r.toString(16).padStart(2,"0");

                    hexColor = "#" + RcolorHex + "0000";
                    console.log(x, y, r, RcolorHex);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", hexColor);
                    svg.appendChild(cell);
                }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I won't be able to help, but just to note, I have different outputs in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vptYU.png) and [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tL4O.png).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to check other browsers. I just tried edge and it works correctly. However, firefox and chrome have the issue of only processing the four highest significance bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that filters use a different color space for their operations.  They use LinearRGB, whereas other colour operations, such as blending to screen, use sRGB.

The solution is to set filters to use sRGB instead.

```
color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
```

```html
<div>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.2/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
             width="1200" height="1024"
             viewBox="0 0 1200 1024" >

      <defs>

          <g id="colormap"></g>
          
          <!-- Filter Definition -->

         
         <filter id="linearred" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="128" intercept="0"/>
          </feComponentTransfer>
         </filter>
          
          
      </defs>
        <g>
            <use id="source" xlink:href="#colormap"/>
            <use y="200"  id= "redoption2" xlink:href="#colormap" filter="url(#linearred)" />
        </g>

    </svg>
</div>
<script>

        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var svg = document.getElementById("colormap");
        var cellSize = 10;
        var colCount = 16

                for (let r = 0; r < 256; r++) {
                    var cell = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
                    var x = (r % colCount)
                    var y = Math.trunc(r/colCount)
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y * cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "width", cellSize);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "height", cellSize);

                    RcolorHex = r.toString(16).padStart(2,"0");

                    hexColor = "#" + RcolorHex + "0000";
                    //console.log(x, y, r, RcolorHex);
                    cell.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", hexColor);
                    svg.appendChild(cell);
                }

</script>
```

It's actually IE/Edge that is wrong here, not Chrome and Firefox :)